# DrawKeypoints in android using openCV

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection

I wanna draw key points in OnCameraFrame, but i get a erro, can someone help me ? I put my code below:

Code:

```
    MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    Mat mat = (Mat) inputFrame;
    FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
    fast.detect(mat, points);


    Scalar redcolor = new Scalar(255,0,0);
    Mat mRgba= mat.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4);
    Core.line(mRgba, new Point(100, 100), new Point(300,300), new Scalar(0, 0, 255));

    Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, points, mRgba, redcolor, 3);


    return mRgba;
```

My LogCat is this:

```
11-26 16:22:49.305: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Starting processing thread
11-26 16:22:51.615: I/Choreographer(22620): Skipped 182 frames!  The application may be doing      too much work on its main thread.
11-26 16:22:51.735: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1382400
11-26 16:22:51.735: I/ActivityManager(22620): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428db6c0 time:135999496
11-26 16:22:51.755: W/dalvikvm(22620): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41875e48)
```

**11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-35591
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620): Process: com.nummist.secondsight, PID: 22620
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620): java.lang.ClassCastException:     org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$JavaCameraFrame cannot be cast to org.opencv.core.Mat
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620):     at com.nummist.secondsight.CameraActivity.onCameraFrame(CameraActivity.java:373)
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620):     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620):     at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
   11-26 16:22:51.755: E/AndroidRuntime(22620):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)**
   11-26 16:22:51.775: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1382400
   11-26 16:22:51.795: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Disconnecting from camera
   11-26 16:22:51.795: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Notify thread
   11-26 16:22:51.795: D/JavaCameraView(22620): Wating for thread

On bold is the red LogCat message

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you have to use:

```
MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();
Mat mat = inputFrame.rgba();
FeatureDetector fast = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
fast.detect(mat, points);


Scalar redcolor = new Scalar(255,0,0);
Mat mRgba= mat.clone();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,4);
Core.line(mRgba, new Point(100, 100), new Point(300,300), new Scalar(0, 0, 255));

Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, points, mRgba, redcolor, 3);


return mRgba;
```

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: Mat mat = inputFrame.rgba();